# Positioning svg next to sibling with dynamic height, so they have equal height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an svg with a fixed aspect ratio which I want to position next to another element with dynamic height and width. The end result should look like the snippet below, but the container element (yellow background) should properly contain all its children.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 24px;
  
  display: inline-flex;
}

.pre {
  background-color: blue;
  animation: changePadding 1000ms infinite alternate;
}

.post {
  background-color: red; // not visible because width is currently 0
  width: fit-content; // doesn't work
}

.post svg {
  height: 100%;
}

@keyframes changePadding {
  from {padding: 0px 0px;}
  to {padding: 10px 10px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pre">Stuff</div>
  <div class="post">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10">
      <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="purple"></circle>
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="10" stroke="red"></line>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also add the code you have that isn't working?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The minimal code to reproduce it is in my question, my actual code is part of a large project I can't just uupload.